# A Map between topological spaces is open iff interior of preimage is a subset of preimage of interior.

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are topological spaces, and $f: X \to Y$ is any map. Show that $f$ is open iff $\forall B \in Y, int(f^{-1}(B)) \subseteq f^{-1}(int B)$.

Comment: Ok but can someone explain why I'm getting downvoted when I'm genuinely trying to learn? Is it because my question is unclear? I'm confused.

Comment: You haven't shared your own thoughts, or tries.

Comment: Ideally, you would show what attepmts at this problem you have made, but even if there are none, you can still share what you already know. What is the definition of the map being open? What is the definition of interior? What other theorems involving these concepts are you aware of?

Comment: @MikeEarnest Thank you, I'll keep that in mind and elaborate next time. Sorry I'm still new to this community. :)

Comment: @JulEighth No problem. If you follow that advice, I think you will find the community rather welcoming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $f$ is open. Let $B \subseteq Y$ and consider $f^{-1}[B]$.

$\operatorname{int}(f^{-1}[B])$ is open and

$$f[\operatorname{int}(f^{-1}[B])] \subseteq f[f^{-1}[B]] \subseteq B$$

so $$f[\operatorname{int}(f^{-1}[B])] \subseteq \operatorname{int}(B)$$ as the latter is the *maximal* open subset of $B$. So by definition of $f^{-1}$ we get that

$$\operatorname{int}(f^{-1}[B]) \subseteq f^{-1}[\operatorname{int}(B)]$$ as required.

And if we have the equality we just shown for all $B \subseteq Y$, consider $O \subseteq O$ open. We want to show $f[O]$ is open. Let's try $B=f[O]$ and we get

$$\operatorname{int}(f^{-1}[f[O]]) \subseteq f^{-1}[\operatorname{int}(f[O])]$$

We know also that $O \subseteq f^{-1}[f[O]]$ so $O \subseteq \operatorname{int}(f^{-1}[f[O]])$ too and so $$O \subseteq f^{-1}[\operatorname{int}(f[O])]$$

which implies $$f[O] \subseteq \operatorname{int}(f[O])$$ which implies that indeed $f[O]$ is open and we're done.

Comment: Thank you so much! For the first direction I tried to start with $f(int(f^{-1}(B))) \subseteq f(f^{-1}(B))$ too but was stuck right after because I didn't realize that $f(f^{-1}(B)) \subseteq B$.  Is it always the case that $B \subseteq f^{-1}(f(B))$ and $f(f^{-1}(B)) \subseteq B$?

Comment: @JulEighth Yes: if $x \in f^{-1}[B]$ by definition we have $f(x) \in B$ so $f[f^{-1}[B]]\subseteq B$ for any $B$. And if $x \in B$ ,$f(x) \in f[B]$ so by definition $x \in f^{-1}[f[B]]$ for the other inclusion. These *should* be standard knowledge from elementary set theory *before* you do a course on topology BTW.

Comment: Haha thanks, I'll definitely review set theory.